# Interactive PDF using iText doesn't work on mobile browsers

Tags: itext

I have created a Interactive PDF using iText libraries in Java. The PDF uses TextFields, DataGrids, buttons, etc. The PDF works fine on Windows 7, Chrome, Safari but doesn't work on mobile browser or other PDF readers on mobile. Is there any alternative i can do this?

Comment: No, many light-weight PDF viewers on mobile devices don't support all the interactive features of a PDF document. You have two options: (1.) serve HTML 5 instead of PDF to a mobile device, or (2) provide a PDF viewer that supports all those functions on a mobile device (I don't know if such viewers exist, but there may be some).

Comment: i think jpedal offers such an html5<->pdf component called jpdf2html5